# Get webpage content with URLSession returns 403

Tags: swift, curl, nsurlsession, urlsession

I'm trying to get contents of a webpage via UrlSession, but the response status code it 403 and checking the body it seems it has a protection for robots.

The strange thing is when I get the page via `curl` it returns the page contents properly.

I Checked the `curl` command with `--verbose` option and there where 3 headers sent via the request. I added them to `URLRequest` and still getting 403 response.
What's the difference between a `curl` `GET` request and `URLSession` request?
How can I simulate the curl request or a browser request vie URLSession?

```swift
 var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
 urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
 urlRequest.setValue("websiteurl.com",forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
 urlRequest.setValue("curl/8.4.0",forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
 urlRequest.setValue("*/*",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
 let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
 print((response as? HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
 // prints out 403
```

Comment: can you post your full code? try to recreate your error.

Comment: This is the full code to get the web  contents. The url is https://dibamovie14.top/ if you want to check the response

Comment: remove the Host and User-Agent headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this in a unit test and works fine:

```
func testExample() throws {
    let exp = expectation(description: "...")
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://dibamovie14.top")!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request).sink {
        print($0)
        exp.fulfill()
    } receiveValue: { data, response in
        print(response)
    }
    
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 4) { error in
        guard let error = error else { return }
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

call is using the dataTaskPublisher but you should be able to apply the changes to your async approach. User-Agent should be set by default anyway when using URLSession and "Host" is not required

**Addendum**:
you can set the User-Agent if you need it but "Host" should not be set:

Host - Header Field
Mandatory since HTTP/1.1.[17] If the request is generated directly in HTTP/2, it should not be used.[18]

**Async Await**

```
func testExampleAsync() async throws {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://dibamovie14.top")!)
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    print((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
}
```

Comment: It works. response code is 200. But what is the difference between `dataTaskPublisher(for: )` and `data(for: )`? the latter returns 403

Comment: `dataTaskPublisher(for: )`uses Combine framework, `data(for: )`is actually the new approach. I used Combine since I just had an example at hand. For details there are lot's of articles out there e.g. https://medium.com/@GetInRhythm/closures-vs-combine-vs-async-await-993eb1da4d44. I added an async await example to the answer